# Absolute Volume Control

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, avrcp

I have an android 4.4.4 device acting as a2dp sink (target). I want to control the volume of this device using the absolute volume control commands from the AVRCP 1.4 Spec.

From my understanding I need to use the class `VolumeProviderCompat` for that but I can't find any example on how to do so.

Am I going in the right direction to use absolute volume control? If yes, does anyone has an example on how to use the `VolumeProviderCompat` class?